# Can get the fact info if i have the fact index?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I'm new at this so it might sound stupid but here we go.

```
(deftemplate player
    (slot nume)
    (slot pozitie)
    (slot goluri)
)

(deftemplate team
    (slot nume)
    (multislot players)
    (slot plasamet)
    (slot goluri (default 0))
)
(defrule goluriEchipa
    ?id <- (echipa (nume ?n) (players $?x ?y $?z)(goluri ?ge))
    (player (nume ?y) (goluri ?gj))
    =>
    (modify ?id (goluri (+ ?gj ?ge)))
)
```

I know why it's stuck in a loop, its because the sum in "goluri" allways changes. So if i remove it like this,

```
(defrule goluriEchipa
    ?id <- (echipa (nume ?n) (jucatori $?x ?y $?z))
    (jucator (nume ?y) (goluri ?gj))
    =>
    (modify ?id (goluri (+ ?gj ?ge)))
)
```

the loop stops but I still need the value from it. I have the fact index, can i get the values?
I saw some examples of `?id:goluri` working in for loops but it doesn't work here.

Edit: I forgot to mention, my goal is to add the sum of all player goals in the team goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is fact-slot-value, but you'll still get looping behavior because fact patterns can be retriggered by changes to slots even if the slot is not present in the pattern.

```
(defrule goluriEchipa
    ?id <- (echipa (nume ?n) (players $?x ?y $?z))
    (jucator (nume ?y) (goluri ?gj))
    =>
    (bind ?ge (fact-slot-value ?id goluri))
    (modify ?id (goluri (+ ?gj ?ge))))
```

Instead you can use the fact query functions:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 2/3/18)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate jucator
   (slot nume)
   (slot pozitie)
   (slot goluri))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate echipa
   (slot nume)
   (multislot players)
   (slot plasamet)
   (slot goluri (default 0)))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts start
   (echipa (nume 1) (players Fred Bill Greg))
   (jucator (nume Fred) (goluri 2))
   (jucator (nume Bill) (goluri 1))
   (jucator (nume Greg) (goluri 3))
   (echipa (nume 2) (players Sam John Ralph))
   (jucator (nume Sam) (goluri 2))
   (jucator (nume John) (goluri 4))
   (jucator (nume Ralph) (goluri 5)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule goluriEchipa
    =>
    (delayed-do-for-all-facts ((?id echipa)) TRUE
       (bind ?sum 0)
       (foreach ?p ?id:players
          (bind ?sum (+ ?sum (do-for-fact ((?j jucator)) (eq ?j:nume ?p) ?j:goluri))))
       (modify ?id (goluri ?sum))))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-2     (jucator (nume Fred) (pozitie nil) (goluri 2))
f-3     (jucator (nume Bill) (pozitie nil) (goluri 1))
f-4     (jucator (nume Greg) (pozitie nil) (goluri 3))
f-6     (jucator (nume Sam) (pozitie nil) (goluri 2))
f-7     (jucator (nume John) (pozitie nil) (goluri 4))
f-8     (jucator (nume Ralph) (pozitie nil) (goluri 5))
f-9     (echipa (nume 1) (players Fred Bill Greg) (plasamet nil) (goluri 6))
f-10    (echipa (nume 2) (players Sam John Ralph) (plasamet nil) (goluri 11))
For a total of 9 facts.
CLIPS>
```